# How to read content from dat file using special delimiter Ç in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

$path=c:\data\test.dat
$reader = get-content -path $path | ConvertFrom-string -Delimiter '¢'

Not splitting using this delimeter but same is working for # delimiter

Test.dat

```
Apple¢Banana¢cheery
Blue¢green¢yellow
```

Want to store the first line as single line as p1 p2 p3 and second lone p1 p2 p3 etc for the entire file

@@{p1=apple; p2=banana; p3=cherry}. @{p1=blue; p2=green; P3= yellow} and so on

Answer (score 0):

> Want to store the first line as single line as p1 p2 p3 and second lone p1 p2 p3 etc for the entire file

You'll want to use `ConvertFrom-Csv` then:

```
$rows = Get-Content $path |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '¢' -Header P1,P2,P3
```